# how to get the page number of a rdlc report in the report body

Tags: dynamic-rdlc-generation

How can i add page number in the report body of a completely dynamic report. 
I have already tried Writing the expression in the text box:

=Globals!PageNumber

or,   ="Page "+ Globals!PageNumber.ToString()+" of "+Globals!TotalPages.ToString()

Thanks in advance

regards
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.
Follow the link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ab9c18bc-ee37-45a2-a52d-628c12d08b33/